# javascript function vs jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in call a function. My example:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var testFunc = function(){
        console.info('call jQuery testFunc');
    }
});

function callJqueryTestFunc(){
    testFunc(); // error - function not exists
}
```

Please, someone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Help with what? and if you are to apologise for a lack of English, at least provide some!

Comment: read about js scopes. In your case `testFunc` variable is declared in another, not parent for `callJqueryTestFunc` scope

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that the function is visible only in scope, where it was created and child scopes. When you have created a function named testFunc inside annonymus jQuery function, then it is visible only inside of it.

You have 2 choces:

- use window object like so:

  window.testFunc = function(){...}
- move it outside of your jQuery annonymus function

But remember that you should not pollute global scope with many functions/objects. It's better to have it clean.

Comment: ... and in child scopes

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was obvious. I have fidex my description.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `testFunc()` doesn't exist within that context i.e. within the `callJqueryTestFunc()`

So, you can pass a variable to the function and call that function like this:

```
var testFunc = function(){
console.info('call jQuery testFunc');
}

});

function callJqueryTestFunc(testFunc){
testFunc(); // now, it exist through closure
}
```

Comment: No, `testFunc` is not a global function so `window.testFunc` won't work.

Comment: Oh yes! Didnt notice the brackets at first!

Comment: i can use console.info(typeof window.testFunc()) and result is undefined :-/

Comment: @LukášVlček when you do `console.info(typeof window.testFunc())` you check result of function `testFunc` but if you try `console.info(typeof window.testFunc)` you get _"function"_

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing with jQuery. It's javascript scopes. For example

```
(function(){

    var testFunc = function(){
        console.info('call jQuery testFunc');
    }

}());

function callJqueryTestFunc(){
    testFunc(); // error - function not exists
}
```

You will get the same error. You cannot access function inside other function

Answer (score 0):

`testFunc` is in another function (a closure) so is not accessible outside of that function.

If you want it accessible, you can attach it to the `window`:

```
jQuery(function($){

    window.testFunc = function(){
        console.info('call jQuery testFunc');
    }

});

function callJqueryTestFunc(){
    testFunc(); // error - function not exists
}
```